# Showing Info Window on click for polygons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show info windows on polygon click but with the solutions on the internet, my code won't work. Because I get all the data that makes the polygon by fetching a `geojson` data. And I'm coloring it too. On click, I can get the clicked polygon's features but can't get the `polygon` itself to open a `infowindow` above it. Can someone help me with these please?

This is the code for my polygon;

```
provinces_of_turkey = new google.maps.Data(); // POLYGON FOR PROVINCES
  provinces_of_turkey.loadGeoJson(
    'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/oividioscaeremos/5db86935a005c1e091657636c3a39b4b/raw/93af322ffef76b1b77384611778beafaf06b6fed/provinces_of_turkey_minified.json'
  );
  provinces_of_turkey.setStyle(function(feature) {
    if(feature.getProperty("NUFUS") > 0 && feature.getProperty("NUFUS") < 50000){
      return ({
        fillColor: '#ffff00',
        zIndex: 3,
        fillOpacity: .65,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1
      });
    }else if(feature.getProperty("NUFUS") > 50001 && feature.getProperty("NUFUS") < 150000){
      return ({
        fillColor: '#ffdb00',
        zIndex: 3,
        fillOpacity: .65,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1
      });
    }else if(feature.getProperty("NUFUS") > 150001 && feature.getProperty("NUFUS") < 250000){
      return ({
        fillColor: '#ffb700',
        zIndex: 3,
        fillOpacity: .65,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1
      });
    }else if(feature.getProperty("NUFUS") > 250001 && feature.getProperty("NUFUS") < 350000){
      return ({
        fillColor: '#ff9300',
        zIndex: 3,
        fillOpacity: .65,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1
      });
    }else if(feature.getProperty("NUFUS") > 350001 && feature.getProperty("NUFUS") < 1000000){
      return ({
        fillColor: '#ff6f00',
        zIndex: 3,
        fillOpacity: .65,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1
      });
    }else if(feature.getProperty("NUFUS") > 1000001 && feature.getProperty("NUFUS") < 3000000){
      return ({
        fillColor: '#ff4b00',
        zIndex: 3,
        fillOpacity: .65,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1
      });
    }else{
      return ({
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        zIndex: 3,
        fillOpacity: .65,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1
      });
    }
  });
```

How can I set a listener for the polygons that are on this map?
 It would also work if I could just get the bounds of the polygon. I can set something for those latlng values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So guys I've found a way that covers my code. Somehow the solution geocodezip suggested didn't work out for me. So I added the listener as google.maps.events listener which seems to work just fine.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(provinces_of_turkey, 'click', function (event) {
    infoWindowPolygons.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infoWindowPolygons.setContent("<h2>"+ event.feature.getProperty("NAME_1")+"</h2>"+
    "<p>Province Population:"+ event.feature.getProperty("NUFUS")+"</p>");
    infoWindowPolygons.open(map);
  });
```

I hope it works for other people too.

Answer (score 1):

[Add an event listener to the data layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#add_event_handlers), use it to open an infowindow.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
  infowindow.setContent("this is an infowindow<br>on letter "+event.feature.getProperty('letter'));
  infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infowindow.open(map);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8vjdpce5/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map with open infowindow]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137
    }
  });

  // NOTE: This uses cross-domain XHR, and may not work on older browsers.
  map.data.loadGeoJson(
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json');

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    infowindow.setContent("this is an infowindow<br>on letter " + event.feature.getProperty('letter'));
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: This didn't work but I added my solution to the question, maybe it could help out some other people. Your answer should've worked but it doesn't really give me a polygon object to play with on "click" action. Must be something about my way of setting the polygons... Thank you for the advise tho, it helped me with my solution.